# How to identify bad sectors when reading a disk

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to check for bad sectors while reading a disk. For one time I am reading 64 sectors at once. Between these 64 sectors some bad sectors are available. I tried it by checking

```
ReadFile(HANDLE,LPVOID,NoOfBytestoRead,NoOfBytesRead,NULL);
```

function. I checked that number of bytes returned(NoOfBytesRead) that has been read and number of bytes(NoOfBytestiRead) that is requested to read. Both values are coming equal. But I think if there are unreadable sectors than NoOfBytesRead should be less than NoOfBytestoRead.

Can anybody help me out, how can I detect the bad sectors while reading the 64 sectors once.

Comment: Known bad sectors are normally taken care of by the disk itself, you're unlikley to see anything via `ReadFile`. What is the `HANDLE` you are passing?

Comment: When we open the disk that time it returns a HANDLE. I am passing that Handle.

Comment: If the function did not return an error, then it did not detect any bad sectors.  What makes you think those sectors are unreadable?

Comment: I made use of third party softwares for checking that hard drive contains bad sectors or not. By that software I thought those sectors are unreadable.